# Dirichlet boundary conditions

Tags: na.numerical-analysis

Hi,
I am using the finite element method to solve current flow in earth.
So far my problem is this
Consider a square,

```
            (air)
        ----(1)------ (air-ground suraface)
        |           |
```

|(ground) (2)....................                (3)  (ground).

```
        |           |
        |           |
        -----(4)-----
           (ground)
```

In (1) (air-ground) I use the homogeneous Neumann conditions, (which the algorithm takes automatic account for).

I make (2)(3)(4) quote large so I apply homogeneous dirichlet conditions.
Current is injecting from some points in (1).

I want to modify it so now (2) (3) and (4) be also air. 
Obviously now homogeneous dirichlet is not the case.

I am thinking two options. 1) If I don’t use dirichlet conditions, then neuman wouldn’t be calculated automatically?  Do I need something more?
2) Shall I use any other boundary conditions is (2)(3)(4)?